# Create TYPO3 Repository of a non-existent table

Tags: typo3

I have a table called `account`. I would like to create a repository called `accountSettings` using the `account` table. The reason I wouldn't want to create a table called `accountSettings` is because all the fields I need already exists in `account` table. However, I would like to have a dedicated repository for the settings pointing to the `account` table. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean `AccountSettings` model? This would mean the repository is called `AccountSettingsRepository`. And are you basically talking about mapping different models to the same table?

Comment: @MathiasBrodala correct. So actually Am thinking of a `AccountSettings` model and a  `AccountSettingsRepository` with fields from `account` table. Something in this lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for how to manually [map a model to an arbitary DB table](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/6-Persistence/4-use-foreign-data-sources.html). So something like this in your `Configuration/Extbase/Persistence/Classes.php` should help you get started:

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

return [
    \MyVendor\MyExtension\Domain\Model\Account::class => [
        'tableName' => 'account',
    ],
    \MyVendor\MyExtension\Domain\Model\AccountSettings::class => [
        'tableName' => 'account',
    ],
];
```

This way you can add properties to your model which match your domain. If necessary you can also define custom `properties` mapping here too, see the linked page.